# How to access a button inside of a class in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using Python 3.8.0 and Tkinter 8.6.
I'm trying to access button *one* through the `button.config`  method but I don't know how to access the button outside the class.

I tried assigning a name to button *one* and then trying `app.name.config()` but it didn't work and Python didn't recognize the name.

```html
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.theWidgets()
    def theWidgets(self):
        self.one = tk.Button(self, text='New Game',command=onePressed())
        self.one.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=100)
        self.two = tk.Button(self, text='Load Game')
        self.two.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=100,pady=10)
        self.three = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit,anchor=tk.W,font='Helvetica 18 bold')
        self.three.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=100, pady=10)

app = Application()

def onePressed():
 #change state of button one to tk.DISABLED

app.mainloop(

)
```

Comment: When you say you are trying to access the button outside the class, what are you trying to do with the button. For example, are you trying to determine which button was pressed?

Comment: I'm trying to change the button's state to disabled so that it disappears when it's clicked.

Comment: You don't change it outside of the class. The function belongs *inside* the class.

Comment: but what use would a button be if I can't edit it outside of the class?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to edit it outside of the class

Comment: because I want to make the button disappear after the button is clicked. So after the button is clicked. the onePressed function is called and the button's state uption is changed to tk.DISABLEd and it disappears.

Comment: Yes, but what I am saying is that you *really* don't want to do that. The actions of a class construct belong *inside* the class.

Comment: so what would be a good-enough alternative so that I can edit the button without having to access the instance *app*?

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn more about basic object-oriented theory? Specifically Encapsulation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming). In short, you build your class in such a way that your class knows a button press results in a disabled button. You neither want nor need any external code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that controls the internal state of a class member (e.g. a button) normally belongs *inside* the class.

The actions of a button press should be defined as part of your class.

(As with anything, there are occasionally exceptions but for now follow the above).

For more details, see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming).

All you need to do in your example is move the button press function inside your class and then associate it with your button (in the same way you associated quit with button 3).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.theWidgets()

    def theWidgets(self):
        self.one = tk.Button(self, text='New Game', command=self.onePressed)
        self.one.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=100)
        self.two = tk.Button(self, text='Load Game')
        self.two.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=100,pady=10)
        self.three = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit, anchor=tk.W, font='Helvetica 18 bold')
        self.three.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=100, pady=10)

    def onePressed(self):
        self.one.config(state="disabled")

app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```